# $.get promise state is resolved but done() is not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I have wired scenario where sometimes the `done()` of a promise is not fired. I did some debugging and I found that the promise state is resolved, `readyState = 4` and `status = 200`.

The promise is already stored in a global variable, so when this scenario happens I do the following code and nothing is logged in the console.

the code is split into two files

the first file initiate the promise conf.js

```
var conf = (function() {
var __globalConfigYaml = join(baseHref, "/conf.yaml?time=" + Date.now()),
    __yamlPromise  =   $.get( __globalConfigYaml);
var members = {
    yaml : {
        promise : __yamlPromise
    }
};
__yamlPromise.done(function(data){
    try{
        var YamlObject = YAML.parse(data.trim());
        $.extend(members.yaml.conf, YamlObject);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        console.log('failed to parse yaml file!');
    }
});
return members;
})();
```

the second file is main.js which has a callback after the promise is resolved

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.when(conf.yaml.promise).done(function () {
       // this code not always executed 
    });
});
```

Comment: Firstly it should be `$.when()`. Secondly we need a much more complete code sample including where you define `promise` and where/when it's resolved. Given the hit/miss presentation of the issue, I'd suspect a race condition.

Comment: I updated the code, I don't think it's a race condition since I can see the request already resolved using the console but when I attach new .then or .done handler it will not be invoked!